# Upgrading GWT from 1.7 to 2.4 using Maven

Tags: gwt, maven

In my project we are using GWT 1.7 and now we want to upgrade it to 2.4. We also using maven 1.6 to build project. I've changed all pom.xml files so they look like this:

```
<properties>        
        <gwt.version>2.4.0</gwt.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now, when i'm trying to build project, it crushes with error:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] artifact not found - Unable to download the artifact from any repository

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command: 
    mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.google.gwt -DartifactId=gwt-dev -Dversion=2.4.0 -Dclassifier=linux-libs -Dpackaging=zip -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
    mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.google.gwt -DartifactId=gwt-dev -Dversion=2.4.0 -Dclassifier=linux-libs -Dpackaging=zip -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]


  com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:zip:2.4.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  smartgwt-maven (http://www.smartclient.com/maven2),
  repo.pentaho.org (http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/pentaho),
  java-net-maven2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2),
  thirdparty.pentaho.org (http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/thirdparty),
  Octo Technology Nexus (http://forge.octo.com/nexus/content/groups/public),
  codehaus-maven-repo (http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/mojo/)
```

I've downloaded files gwt-2.4.0.zip and gwt-servlet-2.4.0.jar, and tried to mvn install both of them, and now i have in my .m2/repository/com/google/gwt/ 4 directories: gwt, gwt-dev, gwt-servlet and gwt-user, all of them have 2.4.0 category inside (some also have old 1.7.0) directory, but the build error still appears.

**UPDATE**

Now i've change version to `<gwt.version>2.5.0-rc1</gwt.version>` , started maven build, i saw when mvn was downloading the required package, but it appears again:

```
com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:jar:2.5.0-rc1
```

not found. I've downloaded the gwt-2.5.0.zip from google website, and there are a lot of .jar files inside, which one should i install?

Comment: There's no type=zip artifact for gwt-dev: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.gwt%7Cgwt-dev%7C2.4.0%7Cjar You apparently don't have such a dependency either in your POM, so are you using a gwt-maven-plugin of some sort?

Comment: I believe so, but i work with gwt and maven only for a few weeks, so how can I know it for sure?

Comment: Run "mvn help:effective-pom" to check the "effective" pom.

Comment: I've got a more than 10000 lines output

Comment: <gwt.version>2.5.0-rc1</gwt.version> can be updated to <gwt.version>2.5.0</gwt.version> .

Comment: We also using maven 1.6 to build project!!! Are you sure... you need to use Maven 2 latest or better yet use maven 3.